# iTunes opens on my iMac automatically

Tags: itunes, macos, imac

iMac with OS X 10.11.5.  iTunes opens with no prompting from me.  I can close it all day and it keeps re-opening.  I rarely want to use it.  How to stop this from happening.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Do you have an iPhone or iPad connected to the computer when this happens?

Comment: iTunes will open up if you press the play/pause media button on your Mac or if you plug in an iOS device to your Mac.

Comment: No, I do not have any phones or pads connected to my iMac.  And, no, I never use the play/pause (F8) button.  I've tried all of the suggestions I've gotten here and elsewhere from other sources and nothing seems to help.

Comment: None of the suggestions here had made any difference.  But, I kept looking and scouring the web and found (I don't remember where) what I thought was a half-assed suggestion that seems to have done the job.

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggestions here had made any difference.  But, I kept looking and scouring the web and found (I don't remember where) what I thought, at first, was a half-assed suggestion that seems to have done the job.  The suggestion was that a "dirty" or misaligned speaker jack could be the issue.  Well, some days ago I removed the speaker plug from the iMac and, lo and behold, the constant opening of iTunes ceased.  I will eventually experiment to see if that was really the issue, but at least temporarily I'm satisfied with using the internal speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the links below. Others have seen similar issues so they might help you out.

[Stop iTunes from opening when a device is plugged in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57493/stop-itunes-from-opening-when-a-device-is-plugged-in)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6078492?tstart=0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: Tried all of the schemes recommended in these links and none of them have any effect on the issue.  iTunes opens on it's own no matter what I do.  Sometimes after I've re-booted it will stay closed for a day (or maybe a few hours) but then it opens by itself.  And, this happens even if I'm far from the iMac (not typing or pressing any keys).  I can't imagine what's initiating this unwanted opening but the best I seem to be able to do is "hide" iTunes; at least it's not annoyingly taking up screen real estate!!

Answer (score -2):

We had the same issue. It turns out that it was the Apple TV controls that was causing it.