# iTunes starts randomly opening every time iPhone is connected -- settings contradict

Tags: iphone, itunes

I've seen a few OLD articles on how to prevent iTunes from opening up every time you plug in your iPhone to your mac; however, none of those solutions seem to work or either they do not exist anymore.

For example, in iTunes preferences, there is no "Open iTunes automatically when this phone is connected" from the phone's summary tab, so I can't uncheck that. "Prevent device from syncing automatically" is also checked off so I'm not sure why it still opens.

Does anyone have any other suggestions on how to fix this? I'm surprised I can't find anything that's more recent and actually works. I'm running the latest version of iTunes and Mac OS X

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop iTunes from opening when a device is plugged in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57493/stop-itunes-from-opening-when-a-device-is-plugged-in)

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes, open "Preferences",
Select "Devices" tab,
Check the box marked "Prevent iPhone, iPods and iPads from syncing automatically"

It started annoying for a few day and this fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

When your iPhone is connected, click the button that has a little iPod on it in the upper left-hand corner of the iTunes window. This should take you to the summary tab by default but if not, "Summary" should be in the list menu on the left. Under the options section, there should be a box you can uncheck/check next to "Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected". Uncheck that box & iTunes shouldn't open anymore when you connect it to your computer (assuming you've already unchecked the "Prevent device from syncing automatically" box in iTunes preferences).

***Note**:
If your iPhone is off or out of battery before it is connected to your computer, iTunes will *still* open automatically *regardless* of prevent sync (iTunes preferences) & automatic sync (summary tab) boxes both being unchecked.